# Eclipse Che error while loading workspace

Tags: eclipse-che

I deployed an Eclipse Che instance in Azure and when I create and access an work space I get an pop-up dialog error. Here is an screenshot of the error message. Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the ephemeral port range for inbound connections